# Call a chocolatey package in powershell based on its package name

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I recently set up a new machine and installed/enabled chocolatey.  As far as I can remember  I was able to call a package via powershell based on the package name. For instance, if I wanted to install mongodb, I used to type `choco install mongodb` - and was able to call the mongo client by simply typing `mongo` in the powershell console. Is there a way to see if something is bound to a specific shim ? or is there an option to enable it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to match packages with shims, but you *can* check the executable a shim points to, along with general information about it and what would happen if you run the shim:

```
shimname.exe --shimgen-noop
```

I tried crafting a command to check all the shims in the `$env:ChocolateyInstall\bin` directory, but there's no guarantee that executables there are going to be a shim. I tried filtering out the known Chocolatey executables as well, but some packages (like `putty`) drop their real executables right in the `bin` folder, and won't respond to the shim parameters like you'd expect.

---

Looking at the [`Install-BinFile`](https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-bin-file) cmdlet, it doesn't look like Chocolatey provides a way to track shims at all as it doesn't even do this itself. I think it uses the same logic to track automatically generated shims at package uninstall time, but any shims explicitly created with `Install-BinFile` also need to have `Uninstall-BinFile` called in the associated `chocolateyUninstall.ps1` script or the shim won't be removed at package uninstall time.

Short of crawling the `$env:ChocolateyInstall\lib\packageName` directory for potential automatic shim names, or the `chocolateyInstall.ps1`/`chocolateyUninstall.ps1` scripts for explicit shims, you're not going to be able to match a shim to a package.